# c# and ms-access database inserting

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbcommand

I want to save data by save button from :

> idbox (textbox) - empbox (combobox) - jobbox (combobox) - unitbox
>   (combobox) -
>
> destbox (combobox) - detectivebox (combobox) - statebox (combobox) -
>
> investdate (datepicker) - investresult  (textbox)

into the table investinside same order :

> id - emp - unit - job - dest - detective - state - investdate -
>   investresult

i tried this one and had no errors but nothing was saved in the table when i check ....

can i know what is the reason for that ?

here's the code i tried

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;


namespace beta_2
{
    public partial class Dentry_main : Form
{
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=beta2.mdb;");
    OleDbDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
    string sql;

    public Dentry_main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Dentry_main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'beta2DataSet.stateinside' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.stateinsideTableAdapter.Fill(this.beta2DataSet.stateinside);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'beta2DataSet.detectivestbl' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.detectivestblTableAdapter.Fill(this.beta2DataSet.detectivestbl);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'beta2DataSet.departments' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.departmentsTableAdapter.Fill(this.beta2DataSet.departments);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'beta2DataSet.units' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.unitsTableAdapter.Fill(this.beta2DataSet.units);
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'beta2DataSet.employees' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.employeesTableAdapter.Fill(this.beta2DataSet.employees);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conn.Open();
        com.Connection = conn;
        sql = "INSERT INTO investinside([id],[emp],[job],[unit],[dest],[detective],[state],[investdate],[investresult])VALUES(@id,@emp,@job,@unit,@dest,@detective,@state,@investdate,@investresult)";
        com.CommandText = sql;
        com.Parameters.Clear();
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp", empbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", jobbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", unitbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dest", destbox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detective", detectivebox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", statebox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@investdate", investdatebox.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@investresult", investresultbox.Text);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("success");
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you sure that you did not copy the database to the project folder when you created this project? Visual studio will do that by default. Check for copies.

Comment: Try to check the result via `int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: How are the database file's properties set.  Is it a resource?  Is it set to `Copy if newer`?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can make ADO.Net easier for you.

If your tables have primarykeys you should take a look at [CommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) feature of ADO.Net.

If so adding data to you table is accomplished by a simple DataTable.Rows.Add and a DataAdapter.Update

If you want to do it manually you can try to go manually all the way.
Instead of:

```
    "INSERT INTO investinside([id],[emp],[job],[unit],[dest],[detective],[state],[investdate],[investresult])VALUES(@id,@emp,@job,@unit,@dest,@detective,@state,@investdate,@investresult)"
```

Try

```
    string.Format("INSERT INTO investinside([id],[emp],[job],[unit],[dest],[detective],[state],[investdate],[investresult])VALUES('{0}','{1}',....)", idbox.Text, empbox.Text,...)
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like to me you are having a local DB connection. This is how I usually connect... 
 "server=USUALLY_YOYR_PC_NAME_CAPPITAL_LETTERS; database=database_name; integrated security=yes"

the last part integrated security is important don't omit it.

Advice: 
  Check out ORM - [Entity Frame Work tutorial from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591506) I much rather work with Objects than SQL statements. Also I make spelling errors all the time. SQL will not forgive those - in Entity Framework you cannot mess up...

Comment: I am afraid you have missed that the OP is using MS Access.